# how to set static url in angular4 routing. this.router.navigate('http://xxxxxx.com/abx/xyz') like this ,

Tags: html, css, angular

how to set static url in angular4 routing.  `this.router.navigate('https://xxxxxx.com/abx/xyz')`
 like this , Which means i want to navigate to another website from my angular
 application.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `window.location.href = '...';`

Comment: i added but i have a doubt, in my Project Redirect to is there so it'll override my window.location.href? – Samudrala Ramu just now

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to redirect to external link

```
window.location.href = "url";
```

Comment: i added but i have a doubt, in my Project Redirect to is there so it'll override my window.location.href?